# Use image instead of labels in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing

I have a plot in ggplot2 with, say, 2 lines, and in the legend I have "Sharks" and "Tigers". Is there a way I could have shark/tiger images appear in the legend instead of that text?

Comment: I'm not going to say that this is impossible, but any solution you get in R is likely to be WAAAAY harder than simply firing up Photoshop. (Looking at `grid.raster` might get you started, though.)

Comment: or [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) for the open source aficionados out there.

Comment: Yeah, doing it by hand in a raster program is a no-go, this is for large-scale repeated graph generation :)

Comment: Vague outline of a solution that might work: make the graph as normal with text labels, render it down to the grid graphics/gtable level, find the grobs for the legend text and replace those with grobs that draw your images instead. This is just a vague suggestion because I'm not even sure how to do some of the steps.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're much better off using `ggsave` to save the figure as a `eps` or `svg`, then opening it in Illustrator (or open source equivalent) and replacing the legend with the images. If you're really dead set on doing it all in R, you can use `annotation_raster` in the current `ggplot2` and add in some text next to it using `geom_text`. Here is a rough attempt:

```
set.seed(10)
library(ggplot2) 
library(RCurl)
library(png)
df <- data.frame(animal = sample(c("sharks", "tigers"),20, rep=T), time=1:20, 
                 scariness = rnorm(20)*-20)

shark <- readPNG(getURLContent("http://i.imgur.com/EOc2V.png"))
tiger <- readPNG(getURLContent("http://i.imgur.com/zjIh5.png"))

ggplot(df, aes(time, scariness, group = animal, color = animal)) + 
geom_line(show_guide = FALSE) +
 annotation_raster(tiger, xmin = nrow(df)-1, xmax = nrow(df), 
    ymin = max(df$scariness)-(.05*max(df$scariness)), 
    ymax = max(df$scariness), interpolate = T) +
 annotation_raster(shark, xmin = nrow(df)-1, xmax = nrow(df), 
    ymin = max(df$scariness)-(.1*max(df$scariness)), 
    ymax = max(df$scariness)-(.05*max(df$scariness)), interpolate = T)
```

[image: shark tiger scariness figure]

Comment: Great code, and let's all consider the "general case," where the OP might want to automate a few dozen graphs of "animal[j] vs animal[k]" and call up a database of images to plot.  GIMP/GraphicConverter/Photoshop might be easier for one graph, but automation always wins when doing 10^n (n>=1) graphs.