# ggplot: legend for emojis in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, emoji

The following code produces a chart with emojis instead of point shapes.[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(emojifont)
load.emojifont("OpenSansEmoji.ttf")

pal <- c("\U1f337"="blue","\U1f370"="red")
set.seed(124)
xdf <- data_frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),
                  label=rep(c("\U1f337","\U1f370"),5))
xdf %>% ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,label=label,color=factor(label))) +
  geom_text(family="OpenSansEmoji") +
  scale_color_manual("object",values=pal) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(labels=FALSE)) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(family="OpenSansEmoji"))
```

It is easy to see that the legend as informative as it could be.
It would be nice to have colored emojis instead of twice the colored letter `a`, and instead of the black emojis, I would like to have the words `tulip` and `cake`.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005015/removing-ggplot-legend-symbol-while-retaining-label This link explains how to remove the "a" from your legend. But making the emojis colored is another issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148404/use-image-instead-of-labels-in-ggplot2-legend You could save the images and use this solution

Answer (score 5):

I haven't worked much with emoji fonts before, but does the following work for you?

**Data wrangling** (I prefer to rename the label column to symbol for convenience, to keep their intended usages separate, but your mileage may vary):

```
xdf2 <- xdf %>%
  rename(symbol = label) %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(symbol == "\U0001f337", "tulip", "cake"))

> xdf2
# A tibble: 10 x 4
         x      y symbol       label
     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>
 1 -1.39    0.318 "\U0001f337" tulip
 2  0.0383 -1.42  "\U0001f370" cake 
 3 -0.763  -0.405 "\U0001f337" tulip
 4  0.212   0.995 "\U0001f370" cake 
 5  1.43    0.959 "\U0001f337" tulip
 6  0.744   0.918 "\U0001f370" cake 
 7  0.700  -0.151 "\U0001f337" tulip
 8 -0.229  -1.22  "\U0001f370" cake 
 9  0.197  -0.869 "\U0001f337" tulip
10  1.21   -1.04  "\U0001f370" cake
```

**Plot**:

```
xdf2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, shape = symbol, color = label)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("tulip" = "blue",
                                "cake" = "red"),
                     guide = guide_legend(
                       override.aes = list(shape = c("\U0001f370",
                                                     "\U0001f337"))
                     ))
```

[image: plot with emoji symbols]

(The actual tulip / cake emojis on my machine look different, for some reason...)